# shell_exec is outputting the data even if not echo'd

Tags: php, shell-exec

I have a small problem with shell_exec. 
It keeps echoing the entire output even when I m not doing echo

```
shell_exec("php blahblahblah.php");
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

From the [PHP docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php):

> shell_exec — Execute command via shell and return the complete output as a string

Notice: "and return the complete output as a string." It's an intrinsic part of `shell_exec`.

To execute a shell command *without* returning the output, consider using the function `exec()` instead.